# How to append a n-dimension image to the end of a (n+1)-dimension image?

Tags: dm-script

I have a 4D dataset with dimensions, e.g., 100(width) x 100(height) x 2048(energy channels) x 20 (frames). 
Is there any function or method to append a 3D datacube (frame) of the same width, height and energy channels to the end of the 4D data set? 
Finally the 4D data set should be 100*100*2048*21.

Answer (score 1):

> **There is no command which expands an image object in this way.**

You have to perform this as a manual copy. (Which requires the additional memory, unfortunately.)

```
number sx = 100
number sy = 100
number sz = 100
number sf = 10

image before := RealImage( "Before", 4, sx, sy, sz, sf )
before = icol
image addFrame := RealImage( "Frame", 4, sx, sy, sz )
addFrame = irow

image after := RealImage( "After", 4, sx, sy, sz, sf + 1)
after.SliceN( 4,4, 0,0,0,0, 0,sx,1, 1,sy,1, 2,sz,1, 3,sf,1 ) = before
after.SliceN( 4,4, 0,0,0,sf, 0,sx,1, 1,sy,1, 2,sz,1, 3,1,1 ) = addFrame
before.showimage()
after.ShowImage()
```

If this is an issue, you can alternatively use the *streaming commands* to directly stream data (values only, no meta data) into either a buffer memory or onto the hard disc. Only at the end, you'd stream that data into an apropriately sized image variable.

Finally, depending on your application, you might consider adding new data as a taggroup to a taglist (which can be appended). You can store "images" as tags ( `TagGroupSetTagAsArray()` ). Again, you could create a 'complete' image form this information at a later time point.

```
number sx = 100
number sy = 100
number sz = 100
number sf = 10

tagGroup FrameTags = NewTagGroup()
tagGroup FrameList = FrameTags.TagGroupGetOrCreateTagList( "frames" )
FrameTags.TagGroupSetTagAsLong( "X Size", sx )
FrameTags.TagGroupSetTagAsLong( "Y Size", sy )
FrameTags.TagGroupSetTagAsLong( "Z Size", sz )
// Add frames whenever you need .....
for( number f = 0; f < sf; f++ )
{
    image addFrame := RealImage( "Frame", 4, sx, sy, sz )
    addFrame = random()
    FrameList.TagGroupInsertTagAsArray( f, addFrame )
}
// Handle taggroup as you want. (Add to global tags, add to image, store to disc... )
FrameTags.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( "frames", 0 )

// Whenever needed, reconstruct image from frames
number nsx, nsy, nsz
FrameTags.TagGroupGetTagAsLong( "X Size", nsx )
FrameTags.TagGroupGetTagAsLong( "Y Size", nsy )
FrameTags.TagGroupGetTagAsLong( "Z Size", nsz )
TagGroup nFrameList
FrameTags.TagGroupGetTagAsTagGroup( "frames", nFrameList )
number nsf = nFrameList.TagGroupCountTags()

image after := RealImage( "After", 4, nsx, nsy, nsz, nsf )
for( number f = 0; f < nsf; f++ )
{
    image addFrame := RealImage( "Frame", 4, sx, sy, sz )
    FrameList.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsArray( f, addFrame )
    after.SliceN( 4,4, 0,0,0,f, 0,sx,1, 1,sy,1, 2,sz,1, 3,1,1) = addFrame
}

after.ShowImage()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed tutorial. One add-on question: since these 4D data can be very huge and very sparse (many zeros), is there any simple way to compress the data (but optimized for access)? Actually, my purpose is to read the multi-framed EDX datacube from Velox and evaluate the data frame by frame in a automated fashion.

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. And certainly not when it is open in DM, because then the data is needed "expanded" for slicing and other operations. Practically, I use the "Save workspace" functionality to store STEM SI data, as it does optional ZIP compression.

Comment: I don't know the Velox format. Can you stream in (binary) with it? If so, that might be a nice option - stream in "what you need" for processing - and stream-out the results.

Comment: Velox uses a very compact Stream Event method to store the 4D SI in 1D:  the number in stream indicates the channel of the EDX-event, if the number is 65535 (max 2byte), this means 'go to the next pixel'. Scanning proceeds along X(fast direction) and Y(slow direction), no marker at the end of X-line the size of a frame is therefore width*height + number of events. In this way, 100*100*2048*10 data with typical 5 events per pixel result in data size of 100*100*(5+1)*10 * 2byte = 1.14MB. However in DM will be 100*100*2048*10 * 2byte = 390 MB! BTW, one need the metadata to reconstruct the stream.

Comment: @w4m Thanks for the info! Sure, storing things "small" is comparatively easy. The problem arises when one wants to act on the data (f.e. with the picker tool or slice tool), because then either you need a complicated access-method (slow) or the memory to hold things. In any case, nothing prevents you from storing DM EDS data with the same algorithm, just using streaming commands. Personally, I found that a simple ZIP (or similar) of the DM4 file does the trick quite conveniently as well.